# Mysql row data return

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the value of column in MySQL and show the result in my page using PHP.

I tried this to get the column value

```
$smt=$conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(Admin_Status) FROM aplic");
$smt->execute();
$result=$smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$res=$result->SUM(Admin_Status);
echo $res;
```

To be more specific, I'm making a PM (personal messaging system) and for that I created the read and unread column in the table, now I want that user see how many new messages (s)he has.

Comment: Give your sum an alias -> `"SELECT SUM(Admin_Status) as AdminStatusSum FROM aplic"` which you can then access -> `$result->AdminStatusSum;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the return value of the query that way because PHP will interpret it as a method to execute.

If you give the field you retrieve an alias in the query, you'll be able to use it correctly from the object.

```
SELECT SUM(Admin_Status) AS status FROM aplic
```

Will allow you to use

```
$result=$smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$res=$result->status;
echo $res;
```

Alternatively, you might be able to use the following syntax

```
$res=$result->{'SUM(Admin_Status)'}
```

But I'd very much vote on using the first alternative and just giving the returned column an alias.